# Facebook open graph return image 50x50 px

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm building an app, and it connects with Facebook.

I try to get the user's profile picture this way:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $_SESSION['FBID']; ?>/picture?type=square ">
```

The image appears to be only 50x50px

Is there a way to get different sizes of the picture?

Comment: Did you try leaving off the `type=square` parameter?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Leaving off the parameter returns it 50x50px if I change the parameter to type=large it will be 200x132px which is also too small.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/ -- You could try setting `width` and `height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the width/height parameters to get a minimum size, Facebook will crop it accordingly:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user-id/picture?width=1000&height=1000
```

Keep in mind that you may not get the exact size, you can only specify the "minimum". For example, with the API call from above, i get a photo that is 1185x1185.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Comment: Great! Thanks man, it's my first time using the facebook Open Graph.

Comment: You might still get smaller images though, if the profile image the user uploaded wasn’t that large to begin with.